# How to apply Linear regression on Pivot table (Any chart)

Tags: pivottable.js

We have a customer issues raw data and trying to apply Linear regression on Pivottable.JS. Ex. We have Month(Mon-YY) in X Axis and No. of issues in Y Axis.
Have written a Linear regression function in Python which returns a Array or any object.
Let us assume we are using a Bar chart and how to print a linear regression Trend  line above it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to do this with PivotTable.js but you may pass additional information to the Renderers via the `rendererOptions` argument to `pivotUI()`, which may enable you to draw additional lines on the chart, depending on the charting renderer you are using.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Nicolas, I have a CSV file with two columns : For example, Day(1,2,3,4,5,6....30) No. of  Issues(30,40,50,60,70,80...90,100) .X-axis is Month(Pivot of Day) and Y-axis is No. of Issues. Now Im getting all kinds of charts, But will need to apply a Linear regression Line above the Bar during run time. We have a independent Linear regression function in Python.Can you please help here?